# XPath extract attribute from <div> in PHP

Tags: php, xpath

i want to extract an attribute from an  and display its value.

```
<div class="b-text-4xl b-text-btc-first b-font-bold btcecc-animated liveup livedown" data-price="38696.15125182" data-live-price="bitcoin" data-rate="1" data-currency="USD" data-timeout="1610051644181"><span>38,696.15</span> <b class="fiat-symbol">$</b></div>
```

I need the value of "data-price".
The location of the full html is at https://www.btc-echo.de/kurs/bitcoin/

I tried this:

```
    $url = "https://www.btc-echo.de/kurs/bitcoin/";
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    $doc->loadHTML(utf8_encode(file_get_contents($url)));
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

    foreach ($xpath->query('*[@id="main"]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/@data-price') as $textNode) {
        echo $textNode->nodeValue;
    }
```

Comment: The XPath you are using may be a bit to specific and not quite right, you could try reducing it to allow a bit of freedom, try `//*[@id="main"]//div/@data-price`

Comment: Yes, that works. Thank you very much.